# Modest DC arc welder with Bipolar transistors

Tags: power-supply, power

I am building a modest 50V/50A welder-variable switchmode power supply.
luckily I have some parts in my junk and salvaged parts, unluckily not all!
I intend to build this welder around a TL494, toroid cores and 4 bipolar bjts BUX23.
I've already mounted them on a heatsink and supported them with U1015 freewheling diode each.
But still I am not sure the design won't be on the verge and the brink of bjt blown as I have the feeling they are not robust enough.
My math and engineering estimation and calculation is modest too, so I need your help to help me decide whether to proceed with:

1. a bridge design where every single transistor is at stake (I've got only 2 pieces spare! ), or
2. pushpull paralleling each too bjts, or
3. single mode paralling the four of them so they are supported and robust.

PS. I've prepared a lot of fuses, breakers, and 220 low amp supply in case.
I have the feeling different topologies have pros and cons but how far can that (single mode) deviate from the power I need?
Thanks a lot for your patience and perserverence.

my schematic is very similar to the one here:

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=isZ9tApXwc4[image]

Comment: Don't post links to videos that have similar schematics. Post your actual circuit with correct values and nothing missing. The devil is in the detail.

Comment: the thermal time constant of 1 millimeter thick silicon is the time constant of 1 meter thick silicon (11,400 seconds) divided by the size_ratio ^2. Thus 11,400 / (1e3 * 1e3) = 11,400 / 1,000,000 = 0.0114 seconds or 11.4 milliSeconds. Because a SHORT CIRCUIT will vastly overstress your transistors, I suggest you implement a shutdown system that is 10X faster, 1.14 milliSeconds.

Comment: some (small signal transistors) have the collector contact on the silicon surface, thus the "active region" of the transistor is just the top 10 microns or top 100 microns of the silicon. The thermal time constant (of 10 microns) is 1.14 microSeconds; and you should plan on protecting the transistors within 10% of that time; remember, you are operating in a short-circuit condition. .

Comment: For normal power transistors, with the collector contact being the ENTIRE BACK SIDE (the case or package or flag) the silicon is thinned to 100 microns (if I recall correctly) before packaging. The heat will be dissipated over the **ENTIRE** 100 micron_thick silicon thickness. The thermal time constant is 114 microseconds, and because you want to operate in short-circuit, I'd implement protection in 10% of that, or 11.4 microSeconds.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf thanks a lot for your suggestions, Iam well aware I have to reign "control" the overflow of current but I am not as keen on that.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf, thanks for your information and suggestions, what about a subsidiary transistor circuit to sense and curb overcurrent consumption of the power output transistors like those utilised in audiopower amplifiers?